# How do I rewrite the JSON object in a file using file system in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have came across the read and write operations using fs in Node Js.

My scenario is like, I have a file having the data like ,

```
[
{
    "Pref":"Freedom",
    "ID":"5545"
},
{
    "Pref":"Growth",
    "ID":"8946545"
}
]
```

I have to replace the Pref of the element whose ID is 5545 using Node js.

How can I do it. Thanks

Comment: By trying to really write something and when stuck then asking that specific problem here

Comment: You may read the file using Node fs API `readFile` or `readFileSync` ( https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html ), make changes and then rewrite the file.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, you wound need to:

1. read JSON data from the file with `fs.readFile()`
2. parse the JSON with `JSON.parse()`
3. find the correct object in the array
4. change the object
5. serialize the object back to JSON with `JSON.stringify()`
6. write the file with `fs.writeFile()`

but this is not that simple as it may look like, because you will have to:

- add locking to writes so that you never do two writes at the same time
- add locking to reads so that you never read while the write is in progress
- handle incorrect JSON
- handle cases of objects that cannot be serialized
- avoid blocking operations (those with "Sync" in their name) anywhere else then in the first tick of the event loop

Considering all of that you should consider using a database to store any data that changes. Some databases like Mongo, Postgres or Redis need to be run as standalone application either on the same or on a different server. Some embedded databases like SQLite don't need a standalone process and can be run directly in your application.

It's not that it is impossible to write to JSON files and then read those files as needed, but the amount of work that you'd have to do to synchronize the access to the data all without accidentally blocking the event loop in the process is much more difficult than just using any database as intended.

Comment: Great explanation @rsp!

Answer (score 0):

You have some data:

```
const data = [
  {
    "Pref":"Freedom",
    "ID":"5545"
  },
  {
    "Pref":"Growth",
    "ID":"8946545"
  }
]
```

First we need to find the element you want to change (use `[0]` to only select the first in case there are multiple items with ID 5545:

```
const objectToChange = data.filter(item => item.ID === "5545")[0]
```

And then change it!

```
objectToChange['Pref'] = "Liberty"
```

We can see the change reflected in the data object:

```
console.log(data)

//  [{
//    ID: "5545",
//    Pref: "Liberty"
//  },{
//    ID: "8946545",
//    Pref: "Growth"
//  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Load file: `let json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json', 'utf-8'));`

2- Update content:

```
json = json.map(el => {
  if(el.ID === "5545") {
    el.Pref = "TEST";
  }
  return el;
});
```

3- Save again maybe?

`fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(json), 'utf-8');`